# NHibernate sluggish performance in FindAll(criteria) query

Tags: performance, nhibernate

I have a very simple mapping file (se below) and a simple class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Domain" 
                   namespace="Domain" default-access="field.camelcase-underscore" 
                   default-lazy="true">
    <class name="PricePropStateView" table="V_PRICE_PROP_STATES">
        <id name="PriceId"                   column="PRICE_ID"           type="long" />
        <property name="DetailId"            column="DETAILS_ID"         type="long" />
        <property name="Moe"                    column="MOE"                    type="string" />
        <property name="PropId"                 column="PROP_ID"                type="long" />
        <property name="PoQteId"                column="PO_QTE_ID"              type="string" />
        <property name="PoLineItemId"           column="LINE_ITEM_ID"           type="string" />
        <property name="PropState"              column="PROP_STATE"             type="string" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The class represents a data set returned by a View in Oracle.  The performance is very slow.  When executed in Toad for Oracle, the result set is returned in less than a second.  When using

```
 DetachedCriteria criteria =
     DetachedCriteria.For<PricePropStateView>()
     .Add(Restrictions.Eq("PoQteId", aQuoteName));

 return FindAll(criteria).ToList();
```

It is very slow...almost 29 seconds.  Any ideas>  Thanks

Comment: Your query is querying a different class than your mapping file  you've shown us.

Comment: @Vadim....oopppss.  That was a typo.  I've edited the question

Comment: When you mean "executing the query in Toad for Oracle", you are saying that you are just pasting there the SQL generated by NHibernate, right?